# Unexpected behavior on marker popups in openlayer.

Tags: openlayers

When I mouse over my markers, sometimes the popup triggers on the marker, and other times it triggers on the coordinates. It appears that it works correct the first or last time an event is registered.  The markersObjs is created dynamically server side from a web service.  It appears not to matter whether I use two cites or a hundred cities.

```
      var map, baseLayer, markers;

        function drawMap( ){
            var markersObjs = {
                'sections' : {
                    'Atlanta' : {id: '01', lat :'-84.42', lon :'33.65'},
                    'Denver' : {id: '02', lat :'-104.87', lon :'39.75'}
                },
                'chapters' : {
                    'Houston' : {id: '03', lat :'-95.35', lon :'29.97'},
                    'Orlando' : {id: '04', lat :'-81.32', lon :'28.43'}
                 }
              };

            map = new OpenLayers.Map("emap");            
            baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Locals Map", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers:"basic"} );
            map.addLayer( baseLayer );
            map.setCenter( new OpenLayers.LonLat( -98, 38 ), 3.5 ); 

            i = null;
            for ( var value in markersObjs ){

                //set the first object in loop show the rest are false
                if(i == null){
                    show = true;
                    i++;
                }else{
                    show = false;
                }
                addMarkers( value, markersObjs[value], show  );
            }
        console.log(map);
        }

        function addMarkers( name, markersOBJ, show ){
          markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( name );             
            markers.setVisibility(show);

            map.addLayer( markers ); 

            for( var value in markersOBJ ){
                marker = new OpenLayers.Marker( new OpenLayers.LonLat( markersOBJ[value].lat, markersOBJ[value].lon ) );
                marker.PlaneID = value;
                marker.LinkID = markersOBJ[value].id;
                markers.addMarker( marker);

                //add on click                     marker.events.register('click', this.PlaneID , function(e){
                    console.log( 'marker(Click):\n');
                    console.log( marker );
                    console.log( '\n');

                    var markerLink = '/regions/?'+this.LinkID;
                    window.open( markerLink, '_top');
                });

                //add mouseover
                marker.events.register('mouseover', marker, function(e){
                    console.log( 'this.PlaneID (mouseOver):\n');
                    console.log( this.PlaneID );
                    console.log( '\n');
                    popup= new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(this.PlaneID,
                                                  new OpenLayers.LonLat( this.lonlat.lon, this.lonlat.lat ),
                                                  null,
                                                  '<div class="mapPopUp">'+this.PlaneID+'<\/div>',
                                                  null, 
                                                  false);          
                    map.addPopup(popup);
                    console.log(map);
                });

                //here add mouseout event
                markers.events.register('mouseout', marker, function(evt) {
                     for(var i=0; i<map.popups.length; i++){
                          if(map.popups[i].id == this.PlaneID){
                            console.log( 'this.PlaneID (mouseOut):\n');
                            console.log( this.PlaneID );
                            console.log( '\n');
                             map.popups[i].destroy();
                             break;
                          }
                       }
                });
             }

         }
```